# How to find a phrase that is NOT at a word boundary from a string in Regex?

Tags: python, regex

Okay so this may be just googling wrong or not reading documentation correctly, but I couldn't find anything on this.

Say I have:

```
sample_str = "rose aaron robert moro"
pat = 'ro'
```

I want to find all instances of words (preferably using re.search()) which DON'T end OR begin in 'ro'. That is, I want one or more character to be before and after 'ro'. So I would want 'aaron' to match, but not at any of the other words in sample_str.

How would I do this? I tried a bunch of things, including '+ro+', but it gave me an error. I am not new to Python but have some trouble with the Regex, so if anyone can please explain that would be great.

Thanks

Comment: https://regex101.com/

Comment: Is regex required?  How about `str` methods?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I believe you can use a negative look-ahead/look-behind for this.

```
\b(?!ro)\w+(?<!ro)\b
```

When applied to `rose aaron robert moro` will match only `aaron`.

#### Explanation

`\b` = a word boundary
`(?!ro)` = not followed by `ro`
`\w+` = one or more word characters
`(?<!ro)\b` = another word boundary, not preceded by `ro`

#### Working Example

https://regex101.com/r/WcSlsx/2/

Comment: I think this is the simplest and best answer. Thanks. 

Also, so the '\b' indicate word boundaries? You can use them to mark the beginning and end of a word?

Answer (score 2):

This problem is simple enough to use `str` methods.  For a non-regex approach:

```
[x for x in sample_str.split() if (not x.startswith(pat)) and (not x.endswith(pat))]
# ['aaron']
```

Note: this will include *any* string that does not start or end with the pattern.  If you wish to extend the condition to include words that contain the pattern, try this:

```
sample_str = "rose aaron robert moro nopattern"
pat = "ro"

[x for x in sample_str.split() if (not x.startswith(pat)) and (not x.endswith(pat)) and (pat in x)]
# ['aaron']
```

Answer (score 1):

I believe *hoipolloi* has the best answer using look-ahead/look-behind. Although, I spent a considerable amount of time trying to figure out how to do this specific case without using extended regexp, enough that I would be disappointed not to share it. Here is the pattern I came up with.

```
r'(?:\b)((?:[^r\s]|(r[^o\s]))\S*(?:([^r\s]o)|[^o\s])|\w|(?:[^r]\s\w)|(?:\w[^o\s]))(?:\b)'
```

You can then use `re.findall` to find all occurence of the pattern.

```
import re

sample_str = "rose aaron robert moro"
pattern = r'(?:\b)((?:[^r\s]|(r[^o\s]))\S*(?:([^r\s]o)|[^o\s])|\w|(?:[^r]\s\w)|(?:\w[^o\s]))(?:\b)'
matchs = re.findall(pattern, sample_str)
```

This is overly complex, impossible to generalize and very ugly. But hey, it was fun.